# React-native splash screen and react-navigation

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to use one of the libraries quoted above, [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) and [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/). I get this

[image: error].

The code is follows:

index.android.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './app/index';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('RecallNotes', () => App);
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Root from 'config/router';
import { 
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-smart-splash-screen';


export default class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount () {
     //SplashScreen.close(SplashScreen.animationType.scale, 850, 500)
        SplashScreen.close({
            animationType: SplashScreen.animationType.scale,
            duration: 850,
            delay: 500,
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <Root />;
    }
}
```

router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import DeckView from 'screens/deckview';

export const Root = StackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: DeckView
    },
},{
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
});
```

deckview.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
  View, 
  Text
} from 'react-native';

 /*
 *  DeckView class
 *  This is the component of the deck image
 */
export default class DeckView extends Component{

    render(){
      return(
        <View> 
            <Text>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
}
```

My question is this: Do I have to use a StackNavigator for my entire navigation for my app or can I keep this above code, after fixing this code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in index.js, change:

`import Root from 'config/router';`

to:

`import { Root } from 'config/router';`

since you are not exporting a default from router.js

Comment: Thanks. So if I am not importing a default from any file in my project, do I have to do that also? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yeah, the way I remember it is that if it's just an `export` there could be any number of them so you have to use `import { myComponent }` to specify which you want.  If you're using `export default` then import expects there to be just one (although, there can still be multiple) so then you just need `import myComponent`.  As to which one you need for libraries and such, check the docs.